# css-only 100% div height with dynamic height footer

Tags: css

I have a three-parts layout: header, content and footer. I am very well familiar with the absolute positioning technique; I use it a lot when I want the content div to extend to 100% of available height.

In this case, my problem is that I don't know in advance the height of the footer, it is dynamic based on its own content, which has an unknown number of lines (typically between 1 to 3 lines).
I want the main content div to grab 100% of available height, after accounting for the height of the header (which is fixed, so it's a no-brainer) and for the height of the footer  therefore I can't use absolute positioning technique here.

I have a solution with involves javascript, but I am trying to find a css-only solution. Ideally, it should be a cross-browser solution (IE8, IE9, chrome, firefox and Safari).

Comment: Mind posting a jsFiddle?

Comment: post what? I don't have a working layout to demonstrate, and it's not like I have a faulty layout which I don't understand why it fails

Comment: That's said, what have you tried? If you tried it out and fail - volia, you _have_ your faulty layout :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;

}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;

   background:#6cf;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">header</div>
   <div id="body">body</div>
   <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the footer is absolutely positioned. It is taken out of normal flow, and does not limit the space occupied by the body. Also, the body isn't stretched to 100% height